# How to Remove black bg from pdf(jspdf)?

Tags: html, css, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I have converting from html to pdf by using html2canvas and jspdf.

I am using a3 format pdf but content width ix 1000px. so after 1000px, pdf shows black background.

```
canvas{
    background: #fff !important;
    background-color: #fff !important
    margin: 0;
}
#cisForm {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

## cisForm is body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
            html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
                background:'#fff',
                document.getElementById("cisForm").appendChild(canvas);
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";

                 l = {
                     orientation: 'p',
                     unit: 'pt',
                     format: 'a3',
                     compress: true,
                     fontSize: 8,
                     lineHeight: 1,
                     autoSize: false,
                     printHeaders: true
                 };

                var doc = new jsPDF(l, "", "");
doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"),"jpeg",0,0)
                window.location=doc.output("datauristring")
            });
        }
    </script>
```

There is no use for this code. This is converting from html to pdf.

and one more question.

Some limited contents only coming in pdf. Some contents are not coming.

Do we need to set no.of pages anywhere?

How to Remove black background from pdf[image]

Comment: I think the problem lies in the fact that html2canvas will give you a png image, with transparent pixels, and that jspdf will convert it to jpg, transforming those transparent pixels to black. Try to set the body and html background to white before you call html2canvas.

Comment: I have setted bg for html body. But it doesnt affect that black color

Comment: Strange, could you make a fiddle? I can't reproduce the issue (ps : there is a lot of unnecessary things in your code)

Comment: I will give in jsfiddle. and one ore problem. all the datas are not coming. It is very lengthy page.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your body background-color to #FFFFFF.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the width you specified.try to adjust the width or specify in html2canvas options.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out this worked for me 
https://github.com/Wildhoney/Canvas-Background#canvas-background

```
import toDataURL from 'canvas-background';

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const data = toDataURL(canvas, '#ffffff', {
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    encoderOptions: 1.0
})
```